# How can I use GitLab under a relative URL on docker?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I'm using gitlab-ce on docker.
These are my system specifications.

- A container of GitLab is gitlab/gitlab-ce.
- The web frontend is using external NGINX.
- GitLab is mounted under /git.

I read the the [gitlab documentation for configuring of a relative url](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/relative_url.html), but it does not work as expected.

All my configurations can be found in the following git project: https://github.com/elda27/test-gitlab

Please advise configuration changes.

Update:
My expected behavior is that I access `http:localhost/git/` as a root of GitLab.
But NGINX or GiLab redirects `/user/_login` instead of `/git/user/_login`.

Comment: Please edit your question and 1) explain exactly what is not working as expected 2) include directly in the question body the relevant part of the configuration which are related to the problem you are witnessing. Meanwhile this question is likely to be moved to https://superuser.com as it is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on SO since not related to programming.

Comment: Thanks for your advise. I don't know superuser.com, and i will ask this site.